# Composite foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

How do I write this constrain in a Laravel migration?

```
ALTER TABLE user_profiles 
   ADD CONSTRAINT app_profiles 
       FOREIGN KEY (profile_id, app_id) 
       REFERENCES profile_apps (profile_id, app_id);
```

I've tried this:

```
$table->foreign(['profile_id', 'app_id'])->references('profile_apps')->on(['profile_id', 'app_id']);
```

which turns into:

> "ErrorException  : Array to string conversion" in
>   C:\Users\CAM\Projects\mcr-back\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php:39

and the same as strings,

```
$table->foreign('profile_id, app_id')->references('profile_apps')->on('profile_id, app_id');
```

with error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column
>   'profile_id, app_id' doesn't exist in table"

Comment: BTW, the ALTER statement runs fine in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mix up `on` and `references` methods using.

Right variant is:

```
$table
    ->foreign(['profile_id', 'app_id'])
    ->references(['profile_id', 'app_id'])
    ->on('profile_apps');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this methoid

**NOTE:** Make sure in your `database > migration` the `profile table` and `app table` is above this `table migration`

> 2014_06_14_23123123_create_profiles_table
>
> 2014_06_14_23123123_create_apps_table

before

> 2014_06_14_23123123_create_this_table

```
$table->foreign('profile_id')->references('id')->on('profiles')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('app_id')->references('id')->on('apps')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I've already set that constrains, those are different from the one I'm asking. The reference needed is to profile_apps, a different table that means that certain profiles belongs to some (but not all) apps. User assigned profiles should exist in that table.

Comment: are you refering to **Many To Many** relationship? or a Polymorphic Relationships.
I suggest you to try this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7T1689IvPQ&t=553s

Comment: Please read the question again. I'm NOT asking for anything related to relationships, but FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINS in migrations. It is simple: sth that I can do in SQL command line I want to do in a Laravel migration.